# In a Kendo Grid how to add a alert when user selects a specific value in "items per page" dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have created a Kendo UI Grid and set pageable to true and added custom page sizes. Now I want to pop up an alert if user selects a value say 10000 in the  "items per page" drop down. Please suggest how can I achieve that.

Comment: well it's a `<select>`.. inside a `<span class="k-pager-sizes"`  maybe write some javascript to handle the change event

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/forums/pagesize-changed-event just had to google

Answer (score 1):

Hook in to the change event for the PageSize dropdown.

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var pageSizeDropDownList = grid.wrapper.children(".k-grid-pager").find("select").data("kendoDropDownList");

pageSizeDropDownList.bind("change", function(e) {
   var pageSize = e.sender.value();
   if (pageSize == "10000")
     {
        // Do Something here
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @JamieD77, the easiest way is probably writting a custom event handler.

Try something like:

```
<script>
 $(function(){
    $("#SomeStaticParentElement .k-grid .k-pager .k-dropdown select").on("change",function(){
         CallCustomFunction();
    });
 }):
</script>
```

Comment: Can you give a little more information than not working? Is it being triggered?

Comment: oh sorry ....not its not being triggered either. Instead in chrome when I am selecting an item in the drop down its pointing to "k-item k-state-selected k-state-focused"